# How do I show text in a pseudo element that spans multiple lines?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to initially hide parts of inline text (spoilers) that will show once clicked. I added a pseudo element to the hidden text to add another text indicating that it covers the spoiler ('show spoiler').

This is what I've got so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.spoiler').attr('title', 'show spoiler').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('noSpoiler spoiler');
  var title = 'hide spoiler' ;
  if( $(this).hasClass('spoiler')){
   title = 'show spoiler';
  };
  $(this).attr('title', title);
 });
});
```

```css
.spoiler {
 position: relative;
 color: transparent;
 background: red;
}

.spoiler:before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: .25em;
 content: 'show spoiler';
 color: blue;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.spoiler:hover {
 cursor: help;
}

.noSpoiler {
 background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}

.noSpoiler:hover {
 cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

The lysine contingency - it’s intended to <span class=spoiler>prevent the spread of the animals in case they ever got off the island</span>. Dr. Wu inserted a gene that makes a single faulty enzyme in protein metabolism. The animals <span class=spoiler>can’t manufacture the amino acid lysine</span>. Unless they’re continually supplied with lysine by us, they’ll slip into a <span class=spoiler>coma</span> and die.
```

Is there a way to show the text in the pseudo element when the spoiler spans multiple lines, but also truncate text in pseudo elements that are too short to show it all?

Comment: You can’t have “inline” behavior with absolute positioning, https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you right. Your problem was the „position: absolute”. You can leave it static. Because the pseudo elements are always before and behind.

If it was wrong maybe you can explain it a little bit more :-)

Have Fun!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.spoiler').attr('title', 'show spoiler').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('noSpoiler spoiler');
  var title = 'hide spoiler' ;
  if( $(this).hasClass('spoiler')){
   title = 'show spoiler';
  };
  $(this).attr('title', title);
 });
});
```

```css
.spoiler {
 position: relative;
 color: transparent;
 background: red;
}

.spoiler:before {
 position: static;
 content: 'show spoiler';
 color: blue;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
  vertical-align: -4px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.spoiler:hover {
 cursor: help;
}

.noSpoiler {
 background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}

.noSpoiler:hover {
 cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

The lysine contingency - it’s intended to <span class=spoiler>prevent the spread of the animals in case they ever got off the island</span>. Dr. Wu inserted a gene that makes a single faulty enzyme in protein metabolism. The animals <span class=spoiler>can’t manufacture the amino acid lysine</span>. Unless they’re continually supplied with lysine by us, they’ll slip into a <span class=spoiler>coma</span> and die.
```

Comment: Thanks Julia, this indeed solves one problem, but introduces others: the spoiler takes up more space, and the 'show spoiler' text is not aligned with the rest…

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to hear that. Sorry for not checking it right before posting. In Chrome everything looked well, but not in Firefox ;-). I just replaced the „vertical-align” with margin-bottom. This worked in both browsers :-).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.spoiler').attr('title', 'show spoiler').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('noSpoiler spoiler');
  var title = 'hide spoiler' ;
  if( $(this).hasClass('spoiler')){
   title = 'show spoiler';
  };
  $(this).attr('title', title);
 });
});
```

```css
.spoiler {
 position: relative;
 color: transparent;
 background: red;
}

.spoiler:before {
 position: static;
 content: 'show spoiler';
 color: blue;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 -5px 5px;
}

.spoiler:hover {
 cursor: help;
}

.noSpoiler {
 background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}

.noSpoiler:hover {
 cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

The lysine contingency - it’s intended to <span class=spoiler>prevent the spread of the animals in case they ever got off the island</span>. Dr. Wu inserted a gene that makes a single faulty enzyme in protein metabolism. The animals <span class=spoiler>can’t manufacture the amino acid lysine</span>. Unless they’re continually supplied with lysine by us, they’ll slip into a <span class=spoiler>coma</span> and die.
```